# Change styling of IonInput-elements in Ionic5 with React

Tags: reactjs, input, styling, ionic5

I want to change the styling (the background-color to be specific) of a simple IonInput under Ionic5 used with React.

```
<IonContent className="ion-padding">
  <IonInput className="username" placeholder="Username" />
  <IonInput type="password" placeholder="Password" />
</IonContent>
```

I already tried adding styles directly to the element with

```
<IonInput
  style={{
   backgroundColor: "red"
  }}
  placeholder="Username"
/>
```

... and adding styles to the corresponding .css file

```
.IonInput {
  background: red;
}
```

but none of those attempts seem to change anything.

Any ideas how I can modify styles in Ionic5-specific HTML-elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve your goal. ionic use css variables heavily. they expose `--background` for us to customize the background color

**1st way: use --background in style directly**

```
<IonInput placeholder="Username" style={{ '--background': '#fff'}} />
```

**2nd way: use className**

```
<IonInput placeholder="Username" className="username" />
```

```
ion-input.username {
  --background: #F00;
}
```

P.S. although the above can fix the style of ion-input, there is a chance where chrome auto input will override the style.

Comment: thanks for your reply. sadly the 1st way doesn't change anything at all. the 2nd way shows the red background for a fraction of a second but is then like immediately "overwritten" with the standard white-color again. any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: 1st way should work. may need to see your code. For 2nd way, I think it is related to the order of your css file which is replacing by lower order css.

Comment: P.S. your custom css files should be imported at last. see if it helps

Comment: You can open the inspector in browser to see which css override the `ion-input.username` in Style section. If you find it, you can post it here

Comment: or try to search your whole project if there is any places defined `--background` somehow which is global and imported at last.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/7HmF25K.png  for your reference. you should be able to see which class is set in the input and see which class is overriding other.

Comment: thanks for your input. I updated my code-example. It seems like my IonContent is overwriting IonInput. But IonContent only has the className "ion-padding" added, which shouldn't affect the color of IonInput (or?). If I remove IonContent, IonInput gets the red-color. Nevertheless it need IonContent around

Comment: Is there any style applied to `ion-padding`?

Comment: no. I can't find any .css in the whole project where some styles are added to ion-padding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232463/discussion-between-mic-fung-and-syzon). Join the room and chat there.